# Debug using MbUnit/Gallio 3.1

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2010, mbunit, gallio

When I use the [Debug] button in Gallio, the breakpoints in my unit tests are not hitting.  The unit tests are written with MbUnit/Gallio.  I am using MbUnit/Gallio version 3.1 build 397 with Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2.  The unit tests run to completion in Gallio Icarus, but they run past the breakpoints.  I see the symbol tables loading in VS, but it does not stop at the expected breakpoint, so I am unable to debug it.

Answer (score 2):

In Gallio Icarus select menu Tools -> Options, select page "Preferences", set "Test Runner Factory" to ***IsolatedAppDomain*** or ***Local*** to get the debugger to work.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything in the Icarus Runtime log?  One problem some people have had is that you can't debug using an instance of Visual Studio running as Administrator from an instance of Icarus that is not.

Answer (score 1):

Normally all my Gallio debugging problems are solved by making the test project **Platform Target** "x86" rather than "Any CPU".

Comment: The Platform Target is grayed out in my Test project.  It's currently set to "N/A".  Know why VS2010 does not allow me to change this setting to "x86"?

Comment: Never seen it being "N/A". For me i's only ever greyed out when I am debugging.

Comment: It's N/A when it's a class library.